# React native Expo: Change application configuration

Tags: react-native, configuration, application-loader, create-react-app, expo

I'm wondering how to change an expo app's configurations. Examples of what I mean by configurations:
Make the app only available for tablets, require location/wi-fi connection/bluetooth connection, specify multiple icon sizes, etc ...
I'm asking this because I generated an ipa, tried to build it with Application Loader but I got this error:

> Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app for
>   iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for
>   iOS versions >= 7.0

Does this have anything to do with `exp.json` ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resizing the Icon to have square values (width = height) did the trick. The icon has to be a square.
See https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/278#issuecomment-309078847

Answer (score 0):

Set application icon in this pixel

[image]

**Most likely your watchKit app icons are not of the correct size. You need follow the instructions in above image**